# Dead keys no longer work in some applications since Ubuntu Jammy

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, 22.04

Since upgrading to 22.04 (Jammy) with Gnome 4, I find that many applications do not respect my keyboard layout, which is English (intl. with AltGr dead keys). This layout normally lets me type characters such as ä©ö conveniently. However since the upgrade, pressing AltGr+c no longer yields © but instead simply c. I wish to keep using the keyboard layout as before.

Applications that used to but no longer do support it:

- firefox (snap)
- keepass xc
- chrome
- VSCodium

Applications that do:

- gedit
- nautilus
- gnome terminal
- ...

Applications that never supported it:

- ms teams

Comment: Try do add another keyboard layout. This helped for me. But it works only till to the reboot :)

Comment: I've changed the following. I'm not sure if it's a true solution but it survives a reboot: Go to Settings > Keyboard > Special Character Entry > set Alternate Characters Key to whatever you want it to be, but not layout default: that seems to not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a true solution but it survives a reboot:

Go to **Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Special Character Entry** > set **Alternate Characters Key** to whatever you want it to be, but not layout default: that seems to not work.

[image: Special Character Entry]

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I had to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and reboot to regain the ability to type in dead keys such as ^ on the Finnish / Swedish keyboard.

Comment: Weird, that worked out of the box on 22.04 for me, but broke on installing 23.04. Thanks, much helpful!